# Adding two bit_vector in VHDL return error "(vcom-1581) No feasible entries for infix operator '+'."

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

This is my code for converting binary to BCD in VHDL

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;

entity bin2bcd is
    port (bin : in bit_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
        clk : in bit;
        bcdout : out bit_vector(4 downto 0) := "00000");
end bin2bcd;

architecture bin2bcdarch of bin2bcd is
begin
    process(clk)
    variable gt9 : bit;
    variable temp : bit_vector(3 downto 0) := "0110";
    variable bcdout_temp : bit_vector(4 downto 0);
    begin 
        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
            gt9 := bin(3) and(bin(2) or bin(1));
            if gt9 = '1' then
                bcdout_temp := ('0' & bin) + ('0' & temp);
            else
                bcdout_temp := ('0' & bin);
            end if;
        end if;
    bcdout <= bcdout_temp;
    end process;
end bin2bcdarch;
```

The problem is when i am trying to add the two bit_vector in the line

`bcdout_temp := ('0' & bin) + ('0' & temp);`

using "+" operator, that I get the error

`(vcom-1581) No feasible entries for infix operator '+'.`

Now, I looked in the web and most of the solutions are for when I use std_logic_vector.

The code works fine if I use std_logic_vector but not when I use bit_vector.

Is there any solution to the problem as to why I am getting the error?

Comment: Is there a good reason that you do not use type `unsigned` along with `use ieee.numeric_std.all;` ?

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate?

I did not use `ieee.numeric_std.all` because I am not using `std_logic_vector`

I also tried doing `unsigned(('0' & bin)) + unsigned(('0' & temp))` but I also get an error for that.

Comment: You need `ieee.numeric_std.all` to use `unsigned`. This would seem more appropriate than `bit_vector`, if the data does represent an unsigned number.

Comment: But using unsigned on bit_vector gives an error

Comment: Why are you using `bit_vector` not `std_logic_vector`?

Comment: ... Or even better `std_ulogic_vector`.

Comment: In -2008 there's numeric_bit_unsigned which allows you to treat bit_vector as unsigned.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor i am using bit_vector, because the software that is used in our CAD Lab in my college is of ancient age and due to some unknown reason, using std_logic doesn't work in that software. No other reason as such.

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks. Used numeric_bit_unsigned and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add bit vectors if you use ieee.numeric_bit_unsigned.all which is part of VHDL-2008. The numeric_std package you're using does not define addition for bit vector.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't use numeric_std but I didn't know about numeric_bit_unsigned. I am giving it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you find your old CAD lab software doesn't support numeric_bit_unsigned you can use type conversions, numeric_bit contains declarations for types signed and unsigned:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;

entity bin2bcd is
    port (bin : in bit_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
        clk : in bit;
        bcdout : out bit_vector(4 downto 0) := "00000");
end bin2bcd;

architecture bin2bcdarch of bin2bcd is
begin
    process(clk)
    variable gt9 : bit;
    variable temp : unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0110";  -- was bit_vector
    variable bcdout_temp : unsigned(4 downto 0);     -- was bit vector
    begin 
        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
            gt9 := bin(3) and(bin(2) or bin(1));
            if gt9 = '1' then
                bcdout_temp := '0' & unsigned(bin) + ('0' & temp);  -- type conversion
            else
                bcdout_temp := '0' & unsigned(bin); -- type conversion
            end if;
        end if;
    bcdout <= bit_vector(bcdout_temp);  -- type conversion
    end process;
end bin2bcdarch;
```

Note temp can also be class constant instead of variable, it's not assigned other than an initial value.

From your comments using WARP2 to synthesis (presumably CPLDs) I recall that it was originally developed to use AHDL as input description and that support for VHDL and Verilog were an afterthought.

You're likely seeing limitations based on what VHDL constructs map to AHDL constructs that are supported for synthesis.

The way to deal with such limitations may be to describe troublesome parts of designs as a dataflow description:

```
entity bin2bcd is
    port (
        bin:    in  bit_vector(3 downto 0);
        clk:    in  bit;
        bcdout: out bit_vector(4 downto 0)
    );
end entity bin2bcd;

architecture dataflow of bin2bcd is
    signal bcdout_temp:     bit_vector(4 downto 0);
begin

    bcdout_temp(4) <=  bin(3) and ( bin(2) or bin(1) ); -- gt9

    bcdout_temp(3) <=  not bcdout_temp(4) and bin(3);   --  zero if gt9 

    bcdout_temp(2) <=  (    bin(3) and bin(2) and bin(1)) or
                       (not bin(3) and bin(2));

    bcdout_temp(1) <= (    bcdout_temp(4) and not bin(1)) or -- gt9 XOR bin(1)
                      (not bcdout_temp(4) and     bin(1));

    bcdout_temp(0) <= bin(0);                           -- doesn't change

REG5:
    process (clk)
    begin
        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
            bcdout <= bcdout_temp;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

While there's no guarantee of this would work better (although likely) it also simulates as VHDL with a testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;

entity bin2bcd_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of bin2bcd_tb is
    signal bin:         bit_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal clk:         bit;
    signal bcdout:      bit_vector(4 downto 0);
begin

DUT:
    entity work. bin2bcd (dataflow)
        port map (
            bin => bin,
            clk => clk,
            bcdout => bcdout
        );

CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 160 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        for i in 0 to 2 ** bin'length - 1 loop
            bin <= bit_vector(to_unsigned(i, bin'length));
            wait for 10 ns;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And shows it gives the right results:

[image: binc2bcd.png]

bin is displayed in decimal while bcdout is displayed in hex.

Comment: I am getting an error saying `(vcom-1581) No feasible entries for infix operator '&'.`

Comment: Have you misapplied the changes shown above? All three of the "&" are [bit, unsigned return unsigned]. Using the wrong package?  I analyzed (compiled) the above code before posting. The "&" operator is predefined for all single dimensional array types.

Comment: Okay, I must have done something wrong then. Sorry for that. i will recheck my code.

Comment: I tried doing the code you posted on the old software named "Galaxy". But i am getting an error saying `C:\warp\lib\common\mod_mthu.vhv (line 175, col 53): (E99) Cannot assign this to an array or record.`

Comment: [REFMANL.PDF](ftp://ece.buap.mx/pub/Secretaria_Academica/SDC/WARP/DOC/REFMANL.PDF)  WARP VHDL Development System, April 1996, Page 258 *E99 : Cannot assign this to an array or record. Only an aggregate with a list of values or another array or record may be assigned to an array or record.* There's no aggregate. What's around mod_mthu.vhv line 175? Can you show the subprogram it's in? It sounds like a tool limitation (superficial lip service to the VHDL standard, possibly one of many limitations that would make it difficult to use, are any of the CPLD's still available?)

Comment: I did not get what you mean by Subprogram? It maybe a tool limitation though.